# Calculate inverse log-weighted similarity in a bimodal network, igraph in Python

Tags: igraph, sna

I'm trying to calculate Adamic-Adar similarity for a network, which have two types of nodes. I'm only interested in calculating similarity between nodes which have outgoing connections. Nodes with incoming connections are a kind of connector and I'm not interested in them.

Data size and characteristic:

```
> summary(g)
IGRAPH DNW- 3852 24478 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
```

Prototype code in Python 2.7:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
from igraph import *

os.chdir("data/")
for file in glob.glob("*.graphml"):
    print(file)
    g = Graph.Read_GraphML(file)
    indegree = Graph.degree(g, mode="in")

    g['indegree'] = indegree
    dev = g.vs.select(indegree == 0)

    m = Graph.similarity_inverse_log_weighted(dev.subgraph())

    df = pd.melt(m)

    df.to_csv(file.split("_only.graphml")[0] + "_similarity.csv", sep=',')
```

There is something wrong with this code, because `dev` is of length `1`, and `m` is `0.0`, so it doesn't work as expected.

*Hint*

I have a *working* code in R, but seems like I'm unable to rewrite it to Python (which I'm doing for the sake of performance, networks are huge). Here it is:

```
   # make sure g is your network
   indegree <- degree(g, mode="in")
   V(g)$indegree <- indegree
   dev <- V(g)[indegree==0]
   m <- similarity.invlogweighted(g, dev)
   x.m <- melt(m)
   colnames(x.m) <- c("dev1", "dev2", "value")
   x.m <- x.m[x.m$value > 0, ]

   write.csv(x.m, file = sub(".csv",
                             "_similarity.csv", filename))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the in-degrees as a *graph* attribute, not as a *vertex* attribute, so you cannot reasonably call `g.vs.select()` later on. You need this instead:

```
indegree = g.degree(mode="in")
g.vs["indegree"] = indegree
dev = g.vs.select(indegree=0)
```

But actually, you could simply write this:

```
dev = g.vs.select(_indegree=0)
```

This works because of how the `select` method works:

> Attribute names inferred from keyword arguments are treated specially
>       if they start with an underscore (`_`). These are not real attributes
>       but refer to specific properties of the vertices, e.g., its degree.
>       The rule is as follows: if an attribute name starts with an underscore,
>       the rest of the name is interpreted as a method of the Graph object.
>       This method is called with the vertex sequence as its first argument
>       (all others left at default values) and vertices are filtered
>       according to the value returned by the method.